If $f,g$ are not continuous at $a$, will $f\cdot g$ or $f/g$ also be not continuous at $a$
Suppose we have functions $f,g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and both functions are not continuous at some point $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, are $f(x)g(x)$ and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ also not continuous at $a$, or are there choices of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that would make the product or the quotient continuous at $a$?
I would like to believe that it is possible to find examples of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ which would make $f(x)g(x)$ or $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ continuous at $a$ using piecewise functions, as I read a post very similar to my question (If $f$ is continuous at $0$, and $g$ is not continuous at $0$, then $fg$ will not be continuous at $0$?), but I would like someone to confirm my intuition.
Any advice would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Easy for the product:  Take $f(x)=1$ identically except that $f(0)=0$ and $g(x)=0$ identically except $g(0)=1$.  Then $f(x)\times g(x)$ is identically $0$.  You can build an example for the quotient similarly, but I'll leave that to you.

Thanks for the prompt feedback! Applying similar logic, I'm wondering would a similar piecewise example to make $f/g$ continuous at 0 work as such: $f(x)=\begin{cases}2, & x \neq 0,\1, & x=0\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x \neq 0,\1/2, & x=0\end{cases}$. So dividing $f$ by $g$ would give the constant function $y=2$. Is this correct?

Sure, that works.  Or, possibly simpler, let $f(x)=1$ identically except $f(0)=2$ and let $g(x)=f(x)$.

Thank you - wow, much simpler than I thought!

As per the comments on the original post...
A counterexample for $f\cdot g$ would be $f(x)=\begin{cases}1, &x\neq a, \\ 0, & x=a\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}0, &x\neq a, \\ 1, & x=a\end{cases}$, where the product would be the constant function $(f\cdot g)(x)=0$.
A counterexample for $\frac{f}{g}$ would be $f(x)=\begin{cases}2, &x\neq a, \\ 1, & x=a\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}1, &x\neq a, \\ \frac{1}{2}, & x=a\end{cases}$, where the quotient would be the constant function $(\frac{f}{g})(x)=2$. A simpler counterexample would be  $f(x)=\begin{cases}1, &x\neq a, \\ 2, & x=a\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=f(x)$, where the quotient would be the constant function $(\frac{f}{g})(x)=1$.
Credits to lulu in the comments in the original posting for help.

If you want to be a bit more pathological, you can consider $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Pick $f=g$. Then $f$ and $g$ are nowhere continuous and we have $f\cdot g = 1 = f/g$ is continuous everywhere.

Consider too, f=$\frac{1}{x-a}$. Then $f/f=1$.

But, also, for $f\cdot g,$ you could've taken $f,g:\Bbb R$ to be continuous and equal everywhere except at a point $a$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\ne 0$, and define $f(a):=2\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $g(a)=\frac12\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=\frac12\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$.
